# How do I create a ListIsomorphic instance for Vector.Unboxed?

Tags: haskell, vector, typeclass

Since it seems that [writing a `ListIsomorphic` instance for generic vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129603/how-do-i-create-a-listisomorphic-instance-for-generic-vectors) is impossible (or not a good idea), I'm trying to write one for `Vector.Unboxed` directly.

```
class ListIsomorphic l where
    toList    :: l a -> [a]
    fromList  :: [a] -> l a

instance ListIsomorphic UV.Vector where
    toList   = UV.toList
    fromList = UV.fromList
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
test.hs:70:14:
    No instance for (UV.Unbox a) arising from a use of ‘UV.toList’
    Possible fix:
    add (UV.Unbox a) to the context of
        the type signature for toList :: UV.Vector a -> [a]
    In the expression: UV.toList
    In an equation for ‘toList’: toList = UV.toList
    In the instance declaration for ‘ListIsomorphic UV.Vector’

test.hs:71:16:
    No instance for (UV.Unbox a) arising from a use of ‘UV.fromList’
    Possible fix:
    add (UV.Unbox a) to the context of
        the type signature for fromList :: [a] -> UV.Vector a
    In the expression: UV.fromList
    In an equation for ‘fromList’: fromList = UV.fromList
    In the instance declaration for ‘ListIsomorphic UV.Vector’
```

I've tried following the compiler error advice but it didn't work. How can I write it?

Comment: That basically just means you can't define this instance. An instance method can't have stricter requirements on its arguments than those given in the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Your `ListIsomorphic` class promises that `fromList` can be applied to *any* type `a`. However, the unboxed vector requires that `a` is an instance of `Unbox`.

You could instead write a class `ListIsomorphicUnboxed` that has:

```
class ListIsomorphicUnboxed l where
    fromListUnboxed :: (Unbox a) => [a] -> l a
    toListUnboxed :: (Unbox a) => l a -> [a]
```

An alternate approach could be to use Constraints (you'll need to add a few language extensions):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class ListIsomorphic l where
    type C l a :: Constraint
    type C l a = () -- default to no constraint

    fromList :: C l a => [a] -> l a
    toList :: C l a => l a -> [a]

instance ListIsomorphic UV.Vector where
    type C UV.Vector a = UV.Unbox a
    toList   = UV.toList
    fromList = UV.fromList
```

(Code untested!)

In this way each instance can have different constraints. This isn't a very common solution, however.

Comment: Is there any way to abbreviate the `(ListIsomorphic l, Elem l a)` constraint?

Comment: Yes, with `ConstraintKinds` you can write `type ListLike l a = (ListIsomorphic l, Elem l a)`. Then use it like `someFunc :: (ListLike l a) => l a -> ...`

Comment: Okay, sorry for the rain of related questions. It seems like I finally managed to get it to work now. Just let me know if this is a bad practice and is likely to break things later?

Comment: @Viclib I don't know of any common complaints about this pattern.